# West Europe Cloud Service on Azure shows in the United States

Tags: azure, ip, cloud

I have a deployed application on Windows Azure in West Europe. However, the IP I have been assigned (168.63.108.xx) is marked as being in the US on http://cqcounter.com/whois/

Is there something wrong with my deployment? If not, what is the reason that it is shown in the US?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That Whois service will show you who **OWNS** the IP Address, and **not WHERE** the actual HOST with that IP Address is. If you want to find the actual host, try some Visual Trace Route services, though even they might not be reliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the whois and how it maps the IP to a location. Take a look at [this file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/F/C/EFC5E4D8-E4EA-4EFE-9356-D8AEEBC85F50/Azure_IP_Ranges.xml), it contains the IP address ranges for the Azure datacenters. Here's what you'll see for West Europe:

```
<subregion name="West Europe">
  ..
  <network>168.63.0.0/19</network>
  <network>168.63.96.0/19</network>
  ..
</subregion>
```

Now, since this is IP range is in CIDR notation, there are a few tools which make it easy to find the complete range, [like this one](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/netMaskResult?ipAddress=168.63.96.0/19). So actually, **168.63.96.0/19** = **168.63.96.0 - 168.63.127.255**. And this range includes 168.63.108.xx. So there's no issue with your deployment and you can be sure it's located in West Europe.